# Hand shaking fails while trying to add PPA repository

Tags: linux-mint, repository

I cannot add any kind off PPA repository. When I execute the following command e.g.:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hotot-team
```

I get the following error:

> Cannot add PPA: '"Error reading
>   https://launchpad.net/api/1.0/~hotot-team/+archive/ppa: (35,
>   'gnutls_handshake() failed: A TLS packet with unexpected length was
>   received.')"'.

I do have access to [launchpad.net](http://launchpad.net) and I can ping it.

What should I do to get this fixed?

*(Linux: Mint 15 Mate)*

Comment: Have you retried? This is often a transitory problem. I could add this just now without problems.

Comment: @Zelda Yes. I've got this error for different repositories.

Comment: Can you go there ( https://launchpad.net/api/1.0/~hotot-team/+archive/ppa) with a browser?

Comment: @StephaneChazelas This is what I see in the browser: http://i.stack.imgur.com/4F7oE.png